# Trouble executing javascript within IE

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've created a script in vba using IE to click on a tab in a webpage. I would like to know how I can initiate a click on that tab using `.execScript`.

When I try like below, It works (not desirable approach):

```
Sub ExecuteScript()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        Html.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector(""a[href='/questions/ask']"").click();"
    End With
End Sub
```

The way I would like to do is the following so that I can use an object variable (adjacent or within) `.execScript`:

```
Set post = Html.querySelector("a[href='/questions/ask']")
Html.parentWindow.execScript "arguments[0].click();", post
```

But, it throws an error pointing at this line `Html.parentWindow.execScript`

```
Run-time error `429`
ActiveX component can't create object
```

***How can I execute javascript within IE?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the variable type so you can pass `post` as string (i.e. the selector). Then you can concatenate in.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExecuteAScript()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument, post As String, item As Object
    post = "a[href='/questions/ask']"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set item = .document.querySelector("" & post & "")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While item Is Nothing

        If Not item Is Nothing Then item.Click

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you must use `execScript` I don't think you can pass back values with javascript `return` call as you can with selenium. You could add a value to the page with js and then read that back in order to return:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExecuteAScript()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    post = "a[href='/questions/ask']"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Do
            Call .document.parentWindow.execScript("document.title = document.querySelectorAll(" & Chr$(34) & post & Chr$(34) & ").length;")
        Loop While .document.Title = 0
        If IsNumeric(.document.Title) And .document.Title > 0 Then Debug.Print "Success"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of it in the first place but the problem is that I wont be able to create any `do loop` or something like `Do: Set post = Html.querySelector("a[href='/questions/ask']"): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing` to check for any element to be present before using this `Html.parentWindow.execScript` line. Thanks